# I'm taking a leave of absence from moderating

Tags: discussion

> **Update 1/20/2020**: called2voyage has resumed moderation, more info [here](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/returning-to-moderation).

I’ve wrestled for some time with how to approach this issue, but I’ve finally come to a decision. The bottom-line is that it appears SE is becoming unhealthy, and I don’t feel it would be wise for me to continue to invest my energy in the duties of a volunteer position on the site. If there were more transparency from SE about their goals, I might be able to give them the benefit of the doubt, but now that it appears large changes are on the horizon with no prior community discussion, I have nothing to put my faith in.

If SE’s intentions here are good, I will be sad to have departed just before those changes went in place, but their recent history of action is too mired in problematic moves for me to cross my fingers and hope for good intentions. I have enjoyed helping build Space Exploration and Astronomy through the moderator role, and I continue to enjoy those communities today. However, I cannot overlook the bigger picture in the platform hosting those communities.

So due to all of this, I have decided to take a leave of absence from Stack Exchange—I will be marking myself as inactive on Space Exploration and Astronomy. The leave may eventually transition into a resignation, but I’ll give time for community response and the possibility of SE making a rapid fundamental shift in communication surrounding the changes (seems like it would take a miracle at this point).

More details about the changes that precipitated this are on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342039/228367).

Comment: It is strange times indeed. I fully support you following your conscience. Keep in touch and we'll all hope for the best.

Comment: @kimholderwantsMonicaback Thanks! I'll definitely keep in touch.

Comment: Your moderation here and in Astronomy have shaped these communities, words fail me...

Comment: Sorry to see you go. For those wondering, if you decide to make this permanent SE can use the upcoming election to elect a second new moderator from the results even after the election is completed, should this be necessary. This has been done before. So, no rush.

Comment: Thanks for the great work maintaining a high signal-to-noise ratio on space stack exchange.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I appreciate that compliment--it means a lot!

Comment: Sorry to see you go. Would anything persuade you to hang on until the elections?

Comment: @JCRM Actually, recent developments currently have me leaning toward staying on. Stay tuned.