# Returning to moderation

Tags: discussion

I've been giving a lot of thought to the question of resignation over the weekend, and one thing that kept going through my head was Jon Ericson's [blog post](http://jlericson.com/2020/01/17/leaving_stack.html). Despite what he had to say about differences with leadership about healthy community management, what stuck with me was Jon's hope that the company could learn how to work with the community and his [desire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342424/228367) to become a moderator again.

Things are pretty bad right now, but toward the end of last week I saw some signs that communication between the community and leadership is not completely severed, if strained. It's not going on through the usual channels, but it's still there and feedback is still being heard to some extent. As I thought about this and what Jon said about having hope, it was hard to deny that it looked like there was still a chance to salvage things, and I think the best way to keep those lines of communication open is to stay on as a mod.

No matter what the future has in store for us, here at Space Exploration we have a great community *now*, and things here have been scarcely impacted by the network drama. I want to continue to support *this* vibrant community as long as I can. Thank you for all the support in response to my leave of absence post! I look forward to resuming work with all of you.

Comment: I would imagine that a large number of people will be happy to hear this.

Comment: FYI to CMs - Jon's name is included here with explicit permission: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53506087#53506087

Comment: What were the usual channels, and what is it going through now? - What are, should be, and more importantly *were* the topics of the discussions that moderators *normally* have with SEI?

Comment: @Mazura Things have improved more since I wrote this message, but I can give a brief overview. The usual channels were Meta Stack Exchange and the Teacher's Lounge (the site-wide moderator chat room). At the point I wrote this message communication was happening via the Stack Moderators Team on Stack Overflow Teams and through selected groups that the SE staff reached out to. Now they have started to flow back into using Meta Stack Exchange for communication. Topics of discussion can vary a lot--the focus is usually on how best to facilitate the community and curate content.